# How To Get All Data[Row] from Ms Database in Dynamic TextBox

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have code like this

```
int cLeft=0;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = " select * FROM DotMatrix;
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
    txt.Top = (cLeft*25) + 124;
    txt.Left = 50;
    txt.Height = 20;
    txt.Width = 259;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txt.Text=reader["Pertanyaan"].ToString();
    }
    if (txt.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pertanyaan  Habis , Akan Redirect Ke Hasil");
    }
    cLeft = cLeft + 1;
    return txt;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   AddNewTextBox();
}
```

My Question is, why textBox just Show 1 Line from Database???
i Want to Show Data[Row] in Pertanyaan Row
Thanks For Answer

Answer (score 0):

This line is looping through every row and constantly overwriting the textbox value:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    txt.Text=reader["Pertanyaan"].ToString();
}
```

So the same textbox is being assigned to over and over.

Your textbox creation code wants to be moved to inside the loop, something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    txt.Top = (cLeft*25) + 124;
    txt.Left = 50;
    txt.Height = 20;
    txt.Width = 259;
    txt.Text=reader["Pertanyaan"].ToString();
    if (txt.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pertanyaan  Habis , Akan Redirect Ke Hasil");
    }
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```